# Display Node or Entity Reference Content

Tags: views, nodes, entities

I can't seem to figure this one out.

Goal: To allow the back end user to select from a list of "leasing contacts" when creating a "property." And have the view show the full content of the "leasing contacts" selected.

So far I have a Content Type for "leasing contacts" with several contacts in there.
I have a Content Type for "properties" which has an Entity Reference field that references the "leasing contacts." 
This works great on the back end, the user can select from the numerous "leasing contacts" when creating the "property".
HOWEVER, I can't seem to understand how to get a view to show the full "leasing contact" content. The view only displays the "leasing contact" name in plain text. How can I get the view to show not only the "leasing contact" name, but all of the other field content that's in the entity.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword you are looking for here is 'relationship'. You want to create a relationship between your two content types using your entity reference field. Once this is enabled, all the fields available for the 'leasing contact' field will be available.

This tutorial from NodeOne is the best out there for explaining the process: http://nodeone.se/en/using-entity-reference-in-views

Comment: I figured it out. Turns out I did not need to use relationships at all. All I needed to do is select Formatter: 'Rendered Entity' View Mode: 'Full content' when adding Fields in the FIELDS area in the view.

In the view, I went to FIELDS, Add Field, 'Content: Leasing Contact' (which I already created as a field in the Content Type) and chose 'Rendered Entity' under Formatter. RENDERED ENTITY!!! is what I was looking for this whole time. Great! Thank you!